# Trying to find the Minimal Polynomial given the Characteristic Polynomial of a Linear Map

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

Let $T:V \to V$ be a linear transformation (where $V$ is a vector space over a field $K$).

Suppose the Characteristic Polynomial of $T$ is $C_T(x) = {(x-\lambda_1)}^{r_1}{(x-\lambda_2)}^{r_2}\dots{(x-\lambda_k)}^{r_k}$ (where $\lambda_i$ are all distinct eigenvalues and $r_i$ are the algebraic multiplicities).

Then, will the Minimal Polynomial of $T$ be $M_T(x)=(x-\lambda_1)(x-\lambda_2)\dots(x-\lambda_k)$?

If it is not always true, can you provide a counter example?

Comment: Did you check this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)?
The minimal polynomial is $(x-\lambda_1)(x-\lambda_2)\dots(x-\lambda_k)$ if and only if $T$ is diagonalizable. For a counter-example try with $T(x,y)=(x,x+y)$.

Comment: This reads like an assignment, especially the last sentence. The minimal polynomial is a multiple of $(x-\lambda_1)\cdots(x-\lambda_k)$, and divides the characteristic polynomial, and all monic polynomials that satisfy both conditions are a possibility. But I will leave it to you to complete the assignment and find examples of each of those situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the minimal polynomial of a linear operator does not always have simple roots (even when the characteristic polynomial is split, your assumption which implies that the minimal polynomial is also split). In fact there is a theorem that says that the operator is diagonalisable *if and only if* its minimal polynomial is split and has simple roots; this characterises precisely the cases where your claim fails.

And any monic polynomial $P$ can be the minimal polynomial of a linear operator; it suffices to take the operator whose matrix (on some basis) is the companion matrix of $P$ (or the transpose of that companion matrix; either will do fine).